# module product tab slider of prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, product-quantity

This is items.tpl module of Prestashop CMS, it shows random productes in home page, i need to not show  products quantity =0.

sry for my bad English.

Thanks for help guys.

```
{if isset($products) && $products}
<div class="{if isset($SNSPRT_EFFECT)}{$SNSPRT_EFFECT}{/if} product_list products-grid grid {if isset($class) && $class} {$class}{/if}">
{if isset($ajax_start) && $ajax_start}
    {assign var='nbstart' value=$ajax_start}
{else}
    {assign var='nbstart' value=0}
{/if}
{counter start=$nbstart skip=1 print=false name=i assign="i"}
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}

    <div class="ajax_block_product item item-animate{if isset($item_class) && $item_class} {$item_class}{/if}">
        {counter name=i}
        {include file="$tpl_dir./product-blockgrid.tpl"}
    </div>
    {if $i % $SNSPRT_XS == 0}<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>{/if}
    {if $i % $SNSPRT_SM == 0}<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>{/if}
    {if $i % $SNSPRT_MD == 0}<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>{/if}
    {if $i % $SNSPRT_LG == 0}<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>{/if}

{/foreach}
</div>

{addJsDefL name=min_item}{l s='Please select at least one product' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=max_item}{l s='You cannot add more than %d product(s) to the product comparison' sprintf=$comparator_max_item js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDef comparator_max_item=$comparator_max_item}
{addJsDef comparedProductsIds=$compared_products}
{/if}
```

Comment: You can also write to the controller that generates $products? and cms version?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not here in TPL file. It is on PHP associated module file. You should look for module displaying products in home page (like blockbestsellers or blocknewproducts) and look for main PHP module file. Inside you should find the MySQL request. For example from blocknewproducts:

```
protected function getNewProducts()
{
    if (!Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR'))
        return;
    $newProducts = false;
    if (Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT'))
        $newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int)Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR'));

    if (!$newProducts && Configuration::get('PS_BLOCK_NEWPRODUCTS_DISPLAY'))
        return;
    return $newProducts;
}
```

You should change this `$newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int)Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR'));` for your own MySQL sentence keeping original behavior but avoiding random.

Good luck